# Is trans-2-butene IR active with regard to its C=C bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy

To be IR active, the vibration of a bond must result in a substantial change in dipole moment. Since trans-2-butene is symmetrical, will the C=C stretch show up on IR?

Something tells me no because if the C=C bond vibrates, there will be no net change in the bond dipole moment, unlike in cis-2-butene. Any polarization one way in trans-2-butene is cancelled out by a polarization in the opposite direction in trans-2-butene. Cis-2-butene, however, has a permanent dipole and any vibration only exacerbates this dipole.

Comment: What about the C-H bonds? They will show in the IR.

Comment: I was thinking specifically of the C=C bond.

Comment: How come something such as 2-butyne is IR inactive according to my book? Couldn't the methyls be moving in different directions here too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16996/discussion-between-ldc3-and-dissenter).

Comment: Dissenter I think Martin has answered your first comment below.  If you would, add a separate question about what you and @LDC3 came up with in chat.  I'm going to leave the second comment for now.

Comment: @jonsca You can always click on the link since I didn't make it private: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16996/discussion-between-ldc3-and-dissenter

Comment: Not IR active, but Raman active. The measured vibrational frequency using Raman spectroscopy is $1682 \pu{cm^{-1}}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $\ce{C=C}$ stretch will not show in IR. The frequency is $\nu_{\ce{C=C}}=1700~\mathrm{cm^{-1}}$ and has A gerade symmetry (DF-BP86/def2-SVP). There is no change in the dipole moment.
[image: c=c stretch]

However, some bending frequencies involving the $\ce{C=C}$ double bond will show up. For example $\nu_{\ce{HC=CH}}=963~\mathrm{cm^{-1}}$ with a medium intensity.
[image: c=c bend]